# How to hide time from Datetime on Listview if time is 00:00

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, data-binding, string-formatting

Simple case. I've a listview with `ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelsList}"`. MyModelsList is list of MyModel elements:

```
public MyViewModel() {
    ...
    _myModelsList = // method that gets items from db
}

private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _myModelsList;
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModelsList
{
    // get.. set..
}
```

... and MyModel contains some Datetime field called MyDate. When I declare MyDate in default way...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelsList}">
    <...>
        <Label Content="{Binding MyDate}" />   
    </...>
</ListView>
```

... achieve this result:

- when time is 00:00 --> `9.23.2018`
- when time is different --> `9.23.2018 11:00 AM`

I want to achieve the same, but without part of date. Is it possible in XAML? I tried different `ContentStringFormat` but always result contained 00:00.

I know how can I do that when MyDate field is declared separately in ViewModel, but how do that when in ViewModel is only MyList declaration and it's binding to Listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Content="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat=T}".
```

You can refer to this documentation page for all the possible value of StringFormat for a  [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

If you still want to hide the time when its 00:00, you can use a trigger like this

```
                <Label>
                    <Label.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat=T}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding MyDate.Hour}" Value="0" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding MyDate.Minute}" Value="0" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding MyDate.Second}" Value="0" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>

                        </Style>
                    </Label.Style>
                </Label>
```

Comment: Yes, I know but how to no display when 00:00?

Comment: I edited my response with a trigger to hide the value when it's 00:00

Comment: let me know if it fixes your issue or if you still need help!